# How to implement a hold-out validation in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

Let's say I'm using the `Sonar` data and I'd like to make a hold-out validation in R. I partitioned the data using the `createFolds` from `caret` package as `folds <- createFolds(mydata$Class, k=5)`.

I would like then to use exactly the fold `mydata[i]` as test data and train a classifier using `mydata[-i]` as train data.

My first thought was to use the `train` function, but I couldn't find any support for hold-out validation. Am I missing something here?

Also, I'd like to be able to use exactly the pre-defined folds as parameter, instead of letting the function partition the data. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to have a hold-out validation set, couldn't you just split your data frame into a training and validation set and only provide the training set to the `caret` package?

Comment: I'm sorry @josilber, but I think I didn't get it. I'm splitting my dataframe into two sets already, but to which function should I pass them?

Comment: It looks like you can actually do it within `caret`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155482/using-a-validation-set-within-caret

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that maybe you want to use 1/5th of the data as a test set and train using the other 4/5ths?

If that is the case, you should used `createDataPartition` first and let `train` do the rest. For example:

```
> library(caret)
> library(mlbench)
> data(Sonar)
> 
> set.seed(1)
> in_train <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 4/5, list = FALSE)
> 
> training <- Sonar[ in_train,]
> testing  <- Sonar[-in_train,]
> 
> nrow(Sonar)
[1] 208
> nrow(training)
[1] 167
> nrow(testing)
[1] 41
> 
> lda_fit <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, method = "lda")
> lda_fit
Linear Discriminant Analysis 

167 samples
 60 predictors
  2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.71      0.416  0.0532       0.108
```