# Custom training rows when using caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation, training-data

I am using the caret package in R to  fit several models.
When I use the trainControl function without setting the index argument everything works fine for various methods. However when I want to set manually the training rows for the different folds through the index argument, I get the following error when fitting:
*Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing*
I tried different method arguments as the documentation doesn't tell which one the user should use with the index argument set.

I will provide an example if the answer is not trivial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you happen to use an older version of R and caret, be sure to use named lists for the `index` parameter (not using such might cause relatively hard to track down errors, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/29)).

Max, the maintainer of caret, stated in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/109474/112731) that in `tuneControl` the `method` parameter does not matter any more if you set the `index` parameter - which makes sense as you thereby define *which samples* your partitions contain, and *how many partitions* you have, which specifies pretty much the resampling process.

Here's a minimal working example as a reference (note the naming of `index`):

```
library(caret)
library(plyr)
# 5CV with 3 repeats = 15 partitions
m1 <- train(x = iris[,1:2], y = iris[,5], method='lda', 
            trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 5, repeats = 3))

# similar behaviour with using index
index <- llply(1:15, function(x) sample(nrow(iris), round(nrow(iris)*4/5)))
names(index) <- 1:15
m2 <- train(x = iris[,1:2], y = iris[,5], method='lda', trControl = trainControl(index = index))
```

This is what your `index` could look like:

```
> str(index)
List of 15
 $ 1 : int [1:120] 47 28 91 54 130 53 37 19 5 85 ...
 $ 2 : int [1:120] 65 58 39 120 127 80 102 145 97 132 ...
 $ 3 : int [1:120] 113 14 7 62 65 99 108 105 76 123 ...
 $ 4 : int [1:120] 124 92 46 1 27 140 33 147 57 6 ...
 [...]
```

PS: if you don't set `indexOut` in `trainControl`, all samples that are *not* in a particular partition of `index` will be used to evaluate the model trained with this partition. This might be undesired in case you want to subset the evaluation samples as well. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36742681/6229919) for more details.

Comment: Yes I used a named list for index and indexOut, still don't understand what happens in my case. Now writing a minimal working example.For the sake of correctness, I think your m2 is not equivalent to repeated 5 fold cross validation. (in k-fold you use k-1 folds for training not just one as your index list does)

Comment: Yes, please add a reproducible example. In my snippet, each resample uses 4/5 of the complete data for training and 1/5 for evaluation, which is in this sense similar to CV with partitions (4 training, 1 evaluation). The difference is that samples in CV partitions are exclusive for this partition - which is not the case with simple train/evaluation splits I've used for reasons of simplicity, as those are chosen randomly anew each time.

Comment: True, my bad I missread. Actually, I found the solution. trainControl perfectly understood my custom index and indexOut lists. It just happend that a predictor had only NA's in the held-out sets. Thanks for your help!